# Save aero-snapped window position

Tags: windows-7, aero-snap

In Windows 7 it's convenient to "aero-snap" a window to the edge of a screen and there are some programs I always expect in a particular position (eg. Windows Explorer snapped to the left, Chrome snapped to the right). The thing is, when I exit the program and run it again the window size and position is what it was *before* being snapped. I can't manually change it to the same position and size (left/right side of the screen, full height) without it being automatically snapped, either. Is there any way I can "save" the snapped position - maybe some registry hack?

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is to first snap the window to the desired location, then manually re-size it a little bit, and then close the window by clicking the red X.

Answer (score 3):

It actually depends on the Application whether to remember the last size and position or not. You cannot control that. What you can do is use another program that runs always and remembers the positions and size for you between the application session. Something like [WindowManager](http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm). It supports Windows 7 it says. And there maybe more alternatives to it.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add my technique, adapted from @Thomas 's answer.

I've found the best way is to move the window with the cursors.  This leaves the window in exactly the same position.

Here's what I do:

1. Areo snap your window to your desired position
2. Right-click the window in the toolbar Click 'Move' (it's important not to move the mouse after you have clicked 'Move'.  I actually find it best to use my laptop track pad because on my work laptop the buttons are separate to the track pad)
3. Press the left cursor once
4. Press the right cursor once
5. Press Enter
6. Close the window

Now the window will open in the aero snapped position.  And you will spend the rest of your days moving windows back and forth with the cursor keys.

You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

By preventing windows from being automatically snapped(You can re-enable window snapping after positioning your desired windows).

The only time Windows doesn't save window positions is when it considers them either maximized or snapped. So if you tell Windows not to snap them (and of course you can drag window borders manually to the edges of the screen) windows will remember their position.

If you drag borders until mouse is stopped by the edge of the work area, the borders won't be at exact pixels as when they are snapped, but let's not be that picky! There's much more important things to do about life.

You can disable automatic window snapping by:

- Going to 'Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center'.
- Clicking 'Make the mouse easier to use'.
- Ticking 'Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen'.

This setting disables Win+Arrow Keys functionality as well. And of course as I said, you can re-enable window snapping after positioning your desired windows

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this is through third party software, such as AquaSnap. Just install it and it will start saving the snapped positions of any windows by default, you don't even have to setup anything.